# Merging JQuery arrays and converting to JSON format

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have a set of JQuery arrays that I need to join into a single array, jsonify and pass to the python script in the back end.

my_jq.js:

```
var a = ['one','two'];
var b = ['three','four'];
var c = ['five'];
var d = ['six','seven','eight'];
```

I tried this, but it does not generate an array:

```
var e = $.merge(a,b,c,d)
var json_array = JSON.stringify(e)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ['one','two'];
var b = ['three','four'];
var c = ['five'];
var d = ['six','seven','eight']; 

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(a.concat(b,c,d));
console.log( myJsonString );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `$.merge` jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) function only takes two parameters. What you have is working but the values in `c` and `d` will be omitted.

You can use `concat`: `[].concat(a,b,c,d)`

or in ES6 with the spread syntax = `var e = [...a, ...b, ...c, ...d]`

Comment: It works - I get an Array object in the Inspect > Console. However, when I am calling array e, it comes back empty